# Launching Android Native Lock Screen

Tags: android, screen, locking, lockscreen

I'm looking for a way to launch the native android lock screen from my application. I've looked around and found code about KeyGuardLock and KeyGuardManager but I believe that only locks the keyboard from working.

REF: http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/03/enabling-and-disabling-lock-screen-in.html

Comment: You can tell it go "go to sleep" using the PowerManager's goToSleep() method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

But I don't know if that really is the same as the native screen lock. I haven't used it myself, just saw the function once in the API Docu and remembered now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use DevicePolicyManager to lock screen..

here is how to do it : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

To unlock..

```
    keyGuard = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        mLock = keyGuard.newKeyguardLock("Your_App");
        mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

To Wake the screen up..

```
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm
                .newWakeLock(
                        (PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                                | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP),
                        "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();
```